How to find what is causing this network behaviour?
On one of my machines, something is trying to access nonexistent machines on my local network.
Results of arp -a:
ISP (192.168.0.254) à XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX [ether] sur eno1
? (192.168.0.231) à <incomplet> sur eno1
? (192.168.0.6) à <incomplet> sur eno1
? (192.168.0.11) à <incomplet> sur eno1
? (192.168.0.190) à <incomplet> sur eno1
? (192.168.0.12) à <incomplet> sur eno1

AnotherMachine.local (192.168.0.119) à XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX [ether] sur eno1
? (192.168.0.147) à <incomplet> sur eno1
? (192.168.0.126) à <incomplet> sur eno1
? (192.168.0.202) à <incomplet> sur eno1
? (192.168.0.102) à <incomplet> sur eno1
? (192.168.0.101) à <incomplet> sur eno1
? (192.168.0.143) à <incomplet> sur eno1

Redacted for some reason...
I would like to know how to find what process is causing this and what actions to take.
I forgot to say what Ubuntu version: 24.04.1 LTS with all packages and snaps up to date.

There is a better place to check for answers to this: networkengineering on SE. Here is a list to start with:  https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50843/what-are-the-reasons-for-seeing-an-incomplete-arp

Hello,My problem does not lie in the fact that the arp query does not get an answer. My problem is that some process on the culprit machine is trying to ping a lot of machines in my network using random IPV4 addresses (and of course, as there are no machines holding theses addresses, the query fails, hence the incomplete keyword). Do you know how could I find the culprit process trying to find what is on my network ?
